# How do you make a fixed navbar using CSS/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone how do you make a horizontal navigation bar that is fixed on top and when you scroll down or up the navigation bar follows, which is similar to Facebook's design and http://naldzgraphics.net

Answer (score 3):

You can fix elements to a certain position on the page irrelevant of scrolling using using some simple CSS

```
#element
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px; /* Fix element 10px from the top of the browser window */
    left: 10px; /* Fix element 10px from the left of the browser window */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS property `position:fixed;`

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j88QA/1/